# Drag, rotate and ease in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, rotation, drag, easing

I need to make a MovieClip rotate around it's center point to the left or right depending on mouse drag. I got some basic semblance of what i want going, but it's pretty hackish. Normally i calculate the angle and such but i only really need to use the distance the mouse travels and apply it to the movieclip and for flavor add some nice easing when you let go.

```
public function Main()
    {
        var wereld:MainScreen = new MainScreen();
        addChild( wereld );
        wereld.x = -510;

        planet = wereld["planet"];

        wereld.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startRotatingWorld );
    }
    private function startRotatingWorld( e:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        m_mouseStartPos = stage.mouseX;

        stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopRotatingWorld );
        stage.addEventListener( Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stopRotatingWorld);
    }
    private function applyRotationToWorld( e:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        //Calculate the rotation
        var distance:Number = (m_mouseStartPos - stage.mouseX) / 10000;
        //apply rotation
        planet.rotation += -distance //* 180 / Math.PI;
    }
    private function stopRotatingWorld():void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, applyRotationToWorld );   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is source and demo of a potential solution for you:
http://wonderfl.net/c/o8t0

I based the drag rotation detection on keith peter's [minimalcomps](http://www.minimalcomps.com/), specifically the [source](https://github.com/minimalcomps/minimalcomps/blob/master/src/com/bit101/components/Knob.as) for his [knob component](http://www.minimalcomps.com/?page_id=5)

In the [Minimal Comp's Knob source](https://github.com/minimalcomps/minimalcomps/blob/master/src/com/bit101/components/Knob.as), you can get rotational, horizontal, and vertical movement in the 'onMouseMoved' function.

Finally I used [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) to handle the easing back. In my code I Tween the 'this' object, but in practice you should create a public value in the object you are tweening and tween that item, so you can have more that one item tweening easily.

If this is for a public facing project, let me know when you've implemented it; wouldn't mind taking a look on what it is for ^_^

Comment: I found another solution that I implemented. If you want i could show it to you. However your answer is pretty good as is your solution so i'll set it as solved :)